# как добавить в код GetRowcount и Getcolumncount

Tags: java, матрицы

```
class Matrix {

    @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return false;
}

    @Override
       public String toString() {
       return "string";
}

    private int[][] arr;

    public Matrix(int m, int n) {
        arr = new int[m][n];


    }
    public Matrix(Matrix m){

    }

    int get(int x, int y) {
        return arr[x][y];
    }
    .getRowCount(); ????
    getColumnCount():???

    void put(int x, int y, int value) {
        arr[x][y] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Equals без hashcode не переопределяется.

Comment: Читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Как то так:

```
    public int getRowCount() {
        return arr.length;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return arr[0].length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(5, 5);
        System.out.println(matrix.getRowCount());
        System.out.println(matrix.getColumnCount());
        matrix = new Matrix(5, 10);
        System.out.println(matrix.getRowCount());
        System.out.println(matrix.getColumnCount());
    }
```